# Ни чем и ничем: различие меж ними

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

"Ничем" - наречие,
Насколько понял я,
А где - "ни чем"?
В чём суть их?
Вы, пожалуйста, скажите...

Comment: Наречие не отвечает на падежный вопрос.

Comment: Алена вообще не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: Это её право. А комментарий верный.

Comment: Лорана тоже.

ЗЫ Хорошее у нас разделение труда. Кто-то на вопросы отвечает, кто-то права качает. Suum cuique. Aka "Jedem das Seine".

Answer (score 4):

Ничем - отрицательное местоимение и всегда пишется слитно, кроме тех случаев, когда вставлен предлог - "ни с чем". Еще  раздельно пишется, когда со словом "чем" употребляется повторяющийся союз "ни - ни" : "Я не знаю ни чем тебя угощать, ни чем тебя развлекать"

Answer (score 1):

Ничем не мог удивить - ни ловкостью, ни смелостью, ни страстностью натуры, ни чем другим.

В чём суть?  Суть в том, что это разные разряды местоимений. Ничем не мог удивить - тв. пад. отрицательного местоимения НИЧТО (ничего, ничем, ни с чем, ни о чём). Раздельно пишется, если внутри имеется предлог.

Ни чем (другим)- вопросительное или относительное местоимение ЧТО (другое) в тв. пад. с повторяющимся союзом НИ-НИ пишется раздельно.

Наречием может быть отрицательное местоимение НИЧТО только в застывшей форме родительного падежа НИЧЕГО в разговорной конструкции: Живу ничего, сносно.(Как?)

Answer (score 0):

*"Ни чем" встречается когда "ни" не отрицание, а усилительная частица.* Главным образом - при отрицании глагола. При этом оно обычно находится под логическим ударением и имеет зависимые слова: *"Я тебе не обязан ни жизнью, ни свободой, ни чем еще".*
Почти всегда его можно заменить на "ни чем-либо", "ни чем другим" и т.п.

"Ничем" как отрицание всегда слино, за исключением случае использования его с предлогами: "ни о чем", "ни за чем" (не смешивать с "нипочем" и/или "ни при чем" - это другой падеж и другая конструкция).

Как наречие "ничем" представить себе просто не могу. Думаю, что это невозможно, "ничем" это действительно отрицательное местоимение. 
А почему именно творительный падеж заинтересовал? Те же вопросы можно задать в отношении любого падежа и получить те же ответы: "ничто" vs "ни что", "ничего" vs "ни чего" и т.д.

Comment: "Я тебе не обязан ни жизнью, ни свободой, ни чем еще"
-НИ-не частица, а союз, его можно заменить другим союзом - И, например.